XPath 3.1 fn:sort order descending
Sorting with XPath 3.1 uses fn:sort(), with up to 3 parameters (target, collation, function).
The question is about the definition and use of the function parameter, which bubbles-up the sort key, how should reverse (descending) sort, on the given key and collation, should be done/handled?
I found no example nor explanation. This sort function seems fairly sophisticated, it would be surprising that it does not handle reverse sorting. But how does it?
Regards.

Good question! See in my answer how one can do a descending sort without using fn:reverse :)
@martin_honnen , what do you think?

Thanks for enlightening use, Dimitre. I thought I had asked about inverting the sort key for strings long time ago on the XML slack and there no one came up with such an idea.

Martin, Unfortunately, there is no such thing (in general) as inverted sort key for a string, but there is an inverted sort key for a string with/for a specific collation.

The function itself allows you to provide a sort key, if that is numeric you can of course reverse the sorting by using the negation function($item) { -$item/value }.
For other options see Dimitre's answer.
Note that progress in ongoing to develop XPath 4 and XQuery 4 and XSLT 4, the current state is that for XPath 4 fn:sort https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xpath-functions-40/Overview.html#func-sort is extended to allow an additional fourth argument with a sequence of values ascending or descending to indicate how the sort for each key returned by the third argument, the key function, is supposed to be ordered.
BaseX (XQuery processor that, with XPath functions being shared between XPath, XQuery and XSLT, and XPath being a subset of XQuery, already implements part of the 4 spec) already supports that fourth argument, see this online fidde example.

Easy, Super. Looking-up to v4. Thank you.

Actually, Martin, there is a way to do descending sort without using fn:reverse.
Also, sorting with multiple key() functions can be done using just one function.

@DimitreNovatchev, thanks, Dimitre, good to have you around.

Quoting @Martin_Honnen:
For other values or in general, you are right, there is no easy option provided by the function but you can call fn:reverse on the result so you have to hope that the XPath query optimizer might do a good job on chaining fn:sort and fn:reverse e.g. ('c', 'a', 'b') => sort() => reverse().
For several (possible) sort keys there is no solution in XPath 3.1.
End of quote.

But this is actually possible.
Here is a complete implementation of descending sort (with any collation) without having to reverse the normal sort.
Note that the code, without the map, is mere 19 well-formatted lines:
let $hexCodepoints := function($input as xs:hexBinary) as xs:integer*
{
  let $hexchars := map{
    "00": 0, "01": 1, "02": 2, "03": 3, "04": 4, "05": 5, "06": 6, "07": 7, "08": 8, "09": 9, "0A": 10, "0B": 11, "0C": 12, "0D": 13, "0E": 14, "0F": 15,
    "10": 16, "11": 17, "12": 18, "13": 19, "14": 20, "15": 21, "16": 22, "17": 23, "18": 24, "19": 25, "1A": 26, "1B": 27, "1C": 28, "1D": 29, "1E": 30, "1F": 31,
    "20": 32, "21": 33, "22": 34, "23": 35, "24": 36, "25": 37, "26": 38, "27": 39, "28": 40, "29": 41, "2A": 42, "2B": 43, "2C": 44, "2D": 45, "2E": 46, "2F": 47,
    "30": 48, "31": 49, "32": 50, "33": 51, "34": 52, "35": 53, "36": 54, "37": 55, "38": 56, "39": 57, "3A": 58, "3B": 59, "3C": 60, "3D": 61, "3E": 62, "3F": 63,
    "40": 64, "41": 65, "42": 66, "43": 67, "44": 68, "45": 69, "46": 70, "47": 71, "48": 72, "49": 73, "4A": 74, "4B": 75, "4C": 76, "4D": 77, "4E": 78, "4F": 79,
    "50": 80, "51": 81, "52": 82, "53": 83, "54": 84, "55": 85, "56": 86, "57": 87, "58": 88, "59": 89, "5A": 90, "5B": 91, "5C": 92, "5D": 93, "5E": 94, "5F": 95,
    "60": 96, "61": 97, "62": 98, "63": 99, "64": 100, "65": 101, "66": 102, "67": 103, "68": 104, "69": 105, "6A": 106, "6B": 107, "6C": 108, "6D": 109, "6E": 110, "6F": 111,
    "70": 112, "71": 113, "72": 114, "73": 115, "74": 116, "75": 117, "76": 118, "77": 119, "78": 120, "79": 121, "7A": 122, "7B": 123, "7C": 124, "7D": 125, "7E": 126, "7F": 127,
    "80": 128, "81": 129, "82": 130, "83": 131, "84": 132, "85": 133, "86": 134, "87": 135, "88": 136, "89": 137, "8A": 138, "8B": 139, "8C": 140, "8D": 141, "8E": 142, "8F": 143,
    "90": 144, "91": 145, "92": 146, "93": 147, "94": 148, "95": 149, "96": 150, "97": 151, "98": 152, "99": 153, "9A": 154, "9B": 155, "9C": 156, "9D": 157, "9E": 158, "9F": 159,
    "A0": 160, "A1": 161, "A2": 162, "A3": 163, "A4": 164, "A5": 165, "A6": 166, "A7": 167, "A8": 168, "A9": 169, "AA": 170, "AB": 171, "AC": 172, "AD": 173, "AE": 174, "AF": 175,
    "B0": 176, "B1": 177, "B2": 178, "B3": 179, "B4": 180, "B5": 181, "B6": 182, "B7": 183, "B8": 184, "B9": 185, "BA": 186, "BB": 187, "BC": 188, "BD": 189, "BE": 190, "BF": 191,
    "C0": 192, "C1": 193, "C2": 194, "C3": 195, "C4": 196, "C5": 197, "C6": 198, "C7": 199, "C8": 200, "C9": 201, "CA": 202, "CB": 203, "CC": 204, "CD": 205, "CE": 206, "CF": 207,
    "D0": 208, "D1": 209, "D2": 210, "D3": 211, "D4": 212, "D5": 213, "D6": 214, "D7": 215, "D8": 216, "D9": 217, "DA": 218, "DB": 219, "DC": 220, "DD": 221, "DE": 222, "DF": 223,
    "E0": 224, "E1": 225, "E2": 226, "E3": 227, "E4": 228, "E5": 229, "E6": 230, "E7": 231, "E8": 232, "E9": 233, "EA": 234, "EB": 235, "EC": 236, "ED": 237, "EE": 238, "EF": 239,
    "F0": 240, "F1": 241, "F2": 242, "F3": 243, "F4": 244, "F5": 245, "F6": 246, "F7": 247, "F8": 248, "F9": 249, "FA": 250, "FB": 251, "FC": 252, "FD": 253, "FE": 254, "FF": 255 },
     $strInput := xs:string($input)
   return
   (
    for $i in 1 to xs:integer(string-length($strInput) div 2),
        $j in 2 * $i -1
     return $hexchars(substring($strInput, $j, 2))
   )
},

$invertBase64Binary := function($input as xs:base64Binary) as xs:integer*
{
  let $hexBin := xs:hexBinary($input),
      $codePoints := $hexCodepoints($hexBin)
   return
   (
     for $cp in $codePoints
      return 255 - $cp,
      260
    )
}
  return
   let $grInput :=  ('', 'α', 'αβγδεζηθ', 'β', 'γ', 'δ', 'ε', 'ζ', 'η', 'θ')
     return
     (
        sort($grInput, 'http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?lang=gr;caseLevel=yes'),
        '==============================',
        sort($grInput, (), function($s) 
        {codepoints-to-string($invertBase64Binary(collation-key($s, 
         'http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?lang=gr;caseLevel=yes')))})
     )

=======================================================
I encourage everyone to  try using the $invertBase64Binary function with any collation they  would like.
Here is the result of the above expression, that uses Greek strings, sorted first in ascending order, and then in descending order, using the collation: "http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?lang=gr;caseLevel=yes"
α
αβγδεζηθ
β
γ
δ
ε
ζ
η
θ
==============================
θ
η
ζ
ε
δ
γ
β
αβγδεζηθ
α


And a screenshot:

And of course, this means that in any fn:sort call it is possible to provide just a single key() function, that returns an array of sort-subkeys - regardless of the sort-direction (Asc or Desc) that we need to have for each sort sub-key.
Do note that one can use the standard XPath 3.1 array:sort function in order to compare two arrays.
Putting this all together, in XPath 3.1 one can perform any kind of sorting (that might seem to require multiple key functions and multiple directions) by just using a single key() function.
